# Cleint IP in tomcat manager server status page

Tags: apache, ip, tomcat7, reverse-proxy

We have two tomcat instances on two different machines and an apache reverse proxy on a separate machine.

We are load balancing the requests from apache to two tomcat instances.
Whenever I hit the url, http://domai.com/app apache redirects the request to one of the tomcat instances but when I browse for the currently serving requests in the tomcat manager server status page, client IP is showing the IP of my laptop. In my opinion it should show apache server IP address...

Any one have any idea about the which IP it should show? The reason why I am asking is, sometimes when I hit the URL tomcat is processing the request and app is opening but few times it takes a lot of time to open and some times it is not opening the page. I checked apache and it is forwarding all the requests to tomcat servers. In tomcat server status page  time is increasing but it takes a lot of time to finish the request.